# Logo won't move left or right inside header tag

Tags: html, css, header, position

I'm trying to put my logo in the center or my page (center of header & above menu nav) It moves away from the menu but doesn't move laterally left or right just stays in the same position no matter what.

I've tried everything searching google and no results show up.Tried making header relative and tried making menu relative.
Here's my code.

```
body {
width: 800px;
margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
background: darkgrey;
font-family: arial;
display: block;
}

#header {
width: 800;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
background: transparent;
}

#h1.logo {
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
}

#tabs{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#content
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2em;
    height: 520px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#tab2 {
  position: relative;
}

#icons img {
  padding-right:5px;
  0% { /* space between content and footer*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 20;
    right: 50px;
  }

}
footer {
  display: inline-block;
        width:800px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 250px;

}

footer ul {list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

footer li {display:inline;
}

footer a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
 float:right;
}

table {border: solid darkgrey thin;
position: relative; 
left: -100px;
z-index: 2;

<body>

<header>
<h1 class="logo">
<img src="images/Logodraft.png" alt="Kieron's Logo" title="Kieron's Logo" />
</h1>
</header>

<!--navigation starts here-->

<!--An unordered list that holds the tab navigation items-->
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="index.html" title="tab1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" title="tab2">About</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html" title="tab3">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html" title="tab4">Blog</a></li>
</ul>

<!--A wrapper for each tab content-->

<div id="content">
</div>
<!--end  content div-->

<footer> <!--footer starts here-->

  <div id="tab3">

 <table border="0" width=1024px height=0px>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logoicon.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="index.html">Home | </a> <a href="about.html">About | </a> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio | </a> <a href="blog.html">Blog</a></td>
    <td align="right"><small>&copy;copyright 2016 Kieron Roberts</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </div>    


</footer> <!--end of footer-->

</body>
```

Comment: 1 problem though, when I began to take the width out of the body tag it stretched everything on the page I want the div and content and menu in the middle and room both on the left and right side of the content not spanning the entire width of the page. I think it's confusing because I have 4 pages and the other 3 pages i haven't updated so the css is looking wonky because it's referencing 2 different html pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this by adding `text-align:center;` to the parent of the image( h1 with a class logo )

I noticed that you have a big gab in the right of your page

**first** : you should not use a width on body you have to create a container and give it a fixed width

**second**: you should not use position in all your page that will mess it up, you should only use it when needed

```
<header>
<h1 class="logo">
<img src="images/Logodraft.png" alt="Kieron's Logo" title="Kieron's Logo" />
</h1>
</header>

<!--navigation starts here-->

<!--An unordered list that holds the tab navigation items-->
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="index.html" title="tab1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" title="tab2">About</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html" title="tab3">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html" title="tab4">Blog</a></li>
</ul>

<!--A wrapper for each tab content-->

<div id="content">
</div>
<!--end  content div-->

<footer> <!--footer starts here-->

  <div id="tab3">
  <!-- change width to 100% and remove height-->
 <table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logoicon.png"/></a></td>
    <td><a href="index.html">Home | </a> <a href="about.html">About | </a> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio | </a> <a href="blog.html">Blog</a></td>
    <td align="right"><small>&copy;copyright 2016 Kieron Roberts</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </div>    


</footer> <!--end of footer-->
```

CSS:

```
body {
/*width: 800px;*/ /*deleted*/
/*margin: 100px auto 0 auto;*//*deleted*/
background: darkgrey;
font-family: arial;
display: block;
}

#header {
width: 800;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
background: transparent;
}
/*
#h1.logo {
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
}*//*deleted*/

#tabs{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#content
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2em;
    height: 520px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#tab2 {
  position: relative;
}

#icons img {
  padding-right:5px;
  0% { /* space between content and footer*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 20;
    right: 50px;
  }

}
footer {
  display: inline-block;
        width:800px;
        text-align: left;
       /* margin-top: 250px;*//*deleted*/

}

footer ul {list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

footer li {display:inline;
}

footer a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
 float:right;
}

table {border: solid darkgrey thin;
position: relative; 
/*left: -100px;*//*deleted*/
z-index: 2;}


/*added*/
.logo{

  text-align: center;
}
```

[**This how it should look like**](https://jsfiddle.net/xqmr2fos/1/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying I added text align center to header and it does nothing.

Comment: I edited my answer text-align works fine but you need to change some of your code

Comment: to chiller 1 problem though, when I began to take the width out of the body tag it stretched everything on the page I want the div and content and menu in the middle and room both on the left and right side of the content not spanning the entire width of the page. I think it's confusing because I have 4 pages and the other 3 pages i haven't updated so the css is looking wonky because it's referencing 2 different html pages.

Comment: you can do that by creating a div that containes all of your elements and giv it a width and margin: 0 auto; to center it in the middle...and for the sides you can use HTML5 (main aside) and spread the width between them to fill the container according to your needs of course

Comment: Thanks to you both chiller and data.

Answer (score 0):

make your header position relative, width 100%

make your logo position relative, give it a width smaller than your header, and make it display block, margin: 0 auto, position relative

Comment: Didn't move at all.

Answer (score 0):

you css is not correct. We use # for ID which is an unique identifier for only one element and we use . for class . So you need to remove # before header and h1 tag.  also you don't close the table css properly [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/4xhctns4/1/)

```
header {
width: 800;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
background: transparent;
}

h1.logo {
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
}
```

```css
   body {

  margin: 0 ;
  background: darkgrey;
  font-family: arial;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  background: transparent;
}

h1.logo {
text-align:center;
}
.img-responsive{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 520px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#tab2 {
  position: relative;
}


footer {
  display: inline-block;

  text-align: left;

}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

footer li {
  display: inline;
}

footer a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
  float: right;
}

table {
  border: solid darkgrey thin;
  position: relative;

  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="logo">

<img class="img-responsive" src="images/Logodraft.png" alt="Kieron's Logo" title="Kieron's Logo" />
</h1>
</header>

<!--navigation starts here-->

<!--An unordered list that holds the tab navigation items-->
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="index.html" title="tab1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html" title="tab2">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="portfolio.html" title="tab3">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.html" title="tab4">Blog</a></li>
</ul>

<!--A wrapper for each tab content-->

<div id="content">
</div>
<!--end  content div-->

<footer>
  <!--footer starts here-->

  <div id="tab3">

    <table border="0" width:100height=0px>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logoicon.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="index.html">Home | </a> <a href="about.html">About | </a> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio | </a> <a href="blog.html">Blog</a></td>
        <td align="right"><small>&copy;copyright 2016 Kieron Roberts</small></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>


</footer>
<!--end of footer-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use text-align: center; on your h1, so that everything inside it will be centered.

Also your CSS has some erros, for example you have

```
#h1.logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
}
```

but inside your HTML you have `<h1 class="logo">`, so if you want to target the img inside the h1 you should use:

```
.logo img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
}
```

What you are targeting in your CSS would be a element with a id name of "h1" and a class name of "logo".

Anyway this is the solution :

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo">
            <img src="images/Logodraft.png" alt="Kieron's Logo" title="Kieron's Logo" />
        </h1>
    </header>

    <!--navigation starts here-->

    <!--An unordered list that holds the tab navigation items-->
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="index.html" title="tab1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" title="tab2">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html" title="tab3">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html" title="tab4">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!--A wrapper for each tab content-->

    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <!--end  content div-->

    <!--footer starts here-->
    <footer>
        <div id="tab3">

        <table border="0" width=1024px height=0px>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logoicon.png" /></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="index.html">Home | </a>
                    <a href="about.html">About | </a>
                    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio | </a>
                    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <small>&copy;copyright 2016 Kieron Roberts</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--end of footer-->

</body>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  background: darkgrey;
  font-family: arial;
}

#header {
  width: 800;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 520px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.logo{
  text-align: center;
}

#tab2 {
  position: relative;
}

#icons img {
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
  right: 50px;
}

footer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

footer li {
  display: inline;
}

footer a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
  float: right;
}

table {
  border: solid darkgrey thin;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```